# "No Suitable Driver for jdbc:mysql..." Error

Tags: java, mysql, jsoup

I have looked through quite a few questions asked by others and haven't manage to find the solution to this problem.

The program I am creating is a web crawler in Java, utilizing Jsoup and MySQL. I am doing the programming in Sublime on Windows at the moment. (Having trouble with Eclipse and am tired of fighting with it)

The program is breaking when I attempt to make the connection in crawler, but the same process works fine in my test program with an essentially identical process.

Here are snippets of the code in question:

```
public void openConnection() throws SQLException, IOException
{
    System.out.print("Opening connection...\n");
    String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
    if (drivers != null) System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers", drivers);
    String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
    maxUrls = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("crawler.maxurls"));

    System.out.print("Connection line...\n");
    //connection is a global
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

With the properties being this:

```
database.properties
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdata
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=passwordofsomedescription
crawler.maxurls=100
crawler.domain=somewebsite.com
crawler.root=http://www.somewebsite.com
```

And the run commands for both this and the test program being the following:

RunCrawler.bat

`java.exe -classpath ".;./mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar;./jsoup-1.7.3.jar" Crawler`

RunTestDB.bat

`java.exe -cp ".;./mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar" TestDB`

Any help will be appreciated. The Crawler needs to use both mySQL as well as Jsoup. The testDB does not.

Also, both programs compile fine. The compile classpaths give no errors (Shown below)

makeCrawler.bat

`javac -classpath "./mysql-connector-java-5.1.29-bin.jar;./jsoup-1.7.3.jar" Crawler.java`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the driver property from the file but it does not seem to be defined.

And you are not instructing the `DriverManager` to use a particular `Driver` to connect to a database.

**Suggestion 1**:

Change you property file to include driver property, as shown below.

```
database.properties
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webdata
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=passwordofsomedescription
crawler.maxurls=100
crawler.domain=somewebsite.com
crawler.root=http://www.somewebsite.com

# Add this line new
jdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**Suggestion 2**:

After adding the drivers property to the file,
let the JVM know to use specific driver for database connection.

```
Class.forName( drivers );
```

***Note***: If you are using `JDBC 4.0` or later then this call is optional.

Comment: Wow... I feel exceptionally stupid. First suggestion seems to have worked. Thank you very very much. EDIT: Wait... It might not have worked. Trying something else. At least its erroring in a different way now.